# Python - proper logging import to classes

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I struggle with proper imports of `logging` to classes. Generally, I would like to avoid showing debug messages in the console and saving several same messages in a log file. However, when running in J. notebook via imported classes, the second class in sequence starts to show debug messages in the console during the initializing. Also, without `if not logger.handlers:` There is a doubling of saved messages every time. The classes import the `get_logger` function during the initializing. What should I do differently? Thx

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

_log_format = f"%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(name)s - " \
              f"(%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s"

def get_timed_rotating_file_handler():
    file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler("zon_logs.log", when='D', interval=30, 
        backupCount=15, delay=False, utc=False)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # Log DEBUG and above to file
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format))
    return file_handler

def get_stream_handler():
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Print INFO and above to console
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format))
    return stream_handler

def get_logger(name="Admin"):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    if not logger.handlers:     
        logger.addHandler(get_timed_rotating_file_handler())
        logger.addHandler(get_stream_handler())
    return logger
```

Comment: When do you call `logging.basicConfig` (if at all)?

Comment: Nowhere... Is that needed?

Comment: It's recommended. It sounds like you are getting the default handlers on the root logger as well as your explicitly added handlers. Use `basicConfig` (or one of the other configuration functions from `logger.config` first, *then* use `get_logger` (if even necessary).

Comment: Hmm not able to solve it... Tried to solve it in many ways, but it seems to me that with the second import of the get_logger function, something reset the console handler so the debug messages started to appear in the console again.

Comment: If you never configure the root logger, then the first time anything uses one of the module-level logging functions, a `StreamHandler` for standard error is added to the root logger.

Comment: Could be it something wrong with using a logger in the superclass? And calling logger via super().__init__ ?

Comment: I'm not sure. But the `logging` module maintains its own "inheritance" hierarchy; any named logger inherits from the root logger, so if anything somewhere uses the root logger, a new `StreamHandler` will be added to the root logger and your loggers will inherit use of that handler as well.

Comment: That, at least, explains why you aren't seeing the duplicate until the second import. If you use `basicConfig`, you'll see the output from the root logger's handler as well. The main issue here may be that you are unnecessarily adding handlers to your loggers when you *should* just be making use of the inherited handler(s).

Comment: @chepner Sorry for radio silence. I've tried `basicConfig`, however, it starts to show me everything in the console. So even the outputs of imported libraries' functions. Anyhow my idea was to use a logger via Parent's `super().__init__` that will import the configuration data and logger. However, the first class is making_configuration, where `self.logger` is obviously imported without Parent's `super()__init__` just directly from logger file. After that second class in sequence is already using Parent's `super()__init__`, where `self.logger` is imported. I hope that's somehow understandable.

Comment: Probably because you didn't pass any arguments to `basicConfig`, which results in a `StreamHandler` for standard error with level WARNING added to the root logger (and thus all loggers). A quick hack would be to set the level to something like 60. But you can also use `logging.config.dictConfig` or `logging.config.fileConfig` to more precisely configure your root logger (and any child loggers).

Comment: Or, you can explicitly configure the root handler with a `logging.NullHandler` to avoid the default `StreamHandler` from being added in the first place.

Comment: @chepner I created a small testing group of files (only printing and logging in classes) and also tried all of your suggestions. But only advance seems to me when I delete `if not logger.handlers` or `if not len(logger.handlers)` then I am getting the info to console and debug, info and all others to log file, however still with doubling the lines ->
[link](https://i.postimg.cc/268WwhVw/image.png) So I will probably need to find another solution on how to stop adding new addHandler?! Or can I share the snippet code structure with you?

Comment: I think you can still add your attempt to solve this to the existing question, and perhaps we can go from there.

Comment: I found this interesting and really beneficial video explaining a lot about logging. So switch my style according to that.

link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L77QExPmI0